# Binary Watch Leetcode - C Indeterminate Solution

Tags: c

Trying to solve [this here](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-watch/) puzzle from leetcode. My code sometimes runs fine with no errors, but other times - with the same input - I get this error message:

> AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
> =================================================================
> ==33==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x63226afa2260 (pc 0x000000401a05 bp 0x7ffecf0326c0 sp 0x7ffecf0326b0 T0)
> ==33==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
> #9 0x7f0b0096982f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
> AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
> ==33==ABORTING

I can't figure out where my code is going wrong. I'm a C newbie so this might be pretty obvious. I went for a backtracking solution using an int called "time" to represent both the minutes and the hours. The first 6 least significant bits are the minutes and the next 4 bits are the hours.

Here's my code:

```
#define REPRSIZE 6
#define HBITS 4
#define MBITS 6
#define TBITS (MBITS + HBITS)
#define HMAX 12
#define MMAX 60

//assumes valid time: first 6 least significant bits = mins, next 4 bits = hours
char *repr(int mins, int hours){
    char *s = (char*)malloc(REPRSIZE * sizeof(char*));
    sprintf(s, "%d:%02d", hours, mins);
    return s;
}

void addIfValid(char **ans, int *returnSize, int time) {
    int mins = time & 0b111111; //6 bits
    int hours = time >> MBITS;
    if (mins < MMAX && hours < HMAX) {
        ans[(*returnSize)++] = repr(mins, hours); //legal ++?
    }
}

void _readBinWatch(int n, char **ans, int *returnSize, int time, int i) {
    if (!n) {
        addIfValid(ans, returnSize, time);
        return ans;
    } else {
        while (i < TBITS) {
            int mask = 1 << i;
            _readBinWatch(n-1, ans, returnSize, time | mask, ++i);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

char **readBinaryWatch(int num, int* returnSize) {
    char **ans = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char *));
    _readBinWatch(num, ans, returnSize, 0, 0);
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: It may be danger that what is pointed at by `returnSize` is not initialized.

Comment: `_readBinWatch` declared `void`but returns value ? just do `return;` in `if (!n) {..}` and remove the other one

Comment: also are you sure you never write out of *addIfValid* because too much elements ?  Compile with debug to know on which line of code your problem occurs, useless to search randomly

Comment: if correcting the extra returns change nothing you have to edit your question to give us how you call *readBinaryWatch* including the value of *num* and `*returnSize`, we need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Big thanks to MikeCAT for solution)

The returnSize was not initialized. All I had to do was add *returnSize = 0;!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty good, not sure with the bug you're getting though. This seems to pass through:

```
char** readBinaryWatch(int num, int* returnSize) {
    char** times = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 512);
    int count = 0;

    for (int h = 0; h < 12; h++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
            int temp = (h << 6) | m;

            if (countOnes(temp) == num) {
                char* temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
                sprintf(temp, "%d:%02d", h % 12, m % 60);
                times[count++] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    *returnSize = count;
    return times;
}

int countOnes(int n) {
    int count = 0;

    while (n) {
        n = n & (n - 1);
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-watch/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.